# Divide a C matrix(pointer to pointer) into t by t grid of tiles

Tags: c

Now I have a C matrix grid[n][n], viewing the board as perfectly overlaid with a t by t grid of tiles (i.e., t divides n, and every tile contains n/t by n/t cells):

For example, It's a 8*8 matrix covered by 2*2 grid of tiles, every tile has 4*4 elements:

Sample matrix:

[image]

And it's a 16*16 matrix covered by 2*2 grid of tiles, every tile has 8*8 elements:

Sample matrix 2:

[image]

```
  int ** grid;
  grid0 = malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));
  grid = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
     grid[i] = &grid0[i * N];

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
     for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        grid[i][j] = 0;
```

Now I want to get each tile separately, like tile at position[0][0].But I don't know how to write calculation part. I saw similar question but the result is stored in 1-D array,

Comment: Show the definition of `grid0` and `grid`. Waht is `t` in your code?

Comment: What do you mean with "get"? Get from the user? Read from file? Address it?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I simplify it a bit.

Note: `calloc` does the same as malloc but it fills the array with 0 bytes.

```
  int i;
  int** grid;

  grid = (int**) calloc(N, sizeof(int *));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
     grid[i] = (int*) calloc(N, sizeof(int));
```

Then as the tiles are fictitious you could not generate a new matrix, you only can move through it using indices controlled by you.
To get the coordinates of any tile I would write a function like so:

```
void get_tile(int index_x, int index_y, int tile_dim, int matrix_dim, int* base_x, int* base_y){

  if(tile_dim == 0)
    return;

  int new_dim = matrix_dim / tile_dim;

  *base_x = index_x * new_dim ;
  *base_y = index_y * new_dim ;

}
```

So in in the `base_x` and `base_y` the function will return the new base coordinates you will have to use to move through the tile.

Keep in mind that the new base coordinates will be living in a new matrix with dim = old_dim / tile_dim;